# How do a Windows debugger get a list of dynamic function tables

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi

I am writing a debugger on Windows and need to get call stacks at some moments. In order to unwind a stack, I use `RtlVirtualUnwind`. I have to pass `RUNTIME_FUNCTION` to it. For loaded modules, it is easy to get their runtime functions. But what about those ones that are added by `RtlAddFunctionTable` and `RtlInstallFunctionTableCallback`? Especially, in case when a debugger attaches to an active process, so that it's just unable to "hook" calls of `RtlAddFunctionTable` and `RtlInstallFunctionTableCallback`.

Is there a way to get access to the dynamic function table list?

Comment: Function tables are used on 64-bit Windows to determine how to unwind or walk the stack. 

"unable to "hook" calls of RtlAddFunctionTable and RtlInstallFunctionTableCallback"  The function returns value is `FALSE`? Whether you want to add a dynamic function table or access the dynamic function table?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT, RtlInstallFunctionTableCallback had been called before my debugger attached the process.

Comment: I always thought that some function tables jump around in memory for security reasons. I guess you have to have that admin elevated permission to call this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [RtlGetFunctionTableListHead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/rtlgetfunctiontablelisthead) may be what you are looking for. This will return a pointer to the head of the function table list that you can then iterate.

Comment: Wow! I've never heard about this function. Thank you a lot!